# switching between python 2.7 and 3.5 on mac OSX 10.7.4?

Tags: macos, python-2.7, python-3.5

I've got both python 2.7 and 3.5 installed on my Mac OSX 10.7.4.
My python script written in 3.5 works fine using the command:

```
python3 <file.py>
```

However, running another script compatible with python 2.7 gives me this error:

```
python testfile.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testfile.py", line 29, in <module>
    br.select_form(name="signinWidget")
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 524, in select_form
mechanize._mechanize.FormNotFoundError: no form matching name 'signinWidget'
```

The script uses  mechanize and BeautifulSoup packages.

```
>which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

I tried:

```
python -m pip install BeautifulSoup,mechanize
```

but it does not resolve this.

How do I ensure that the script is pointing to the correct packages which are installed on my mac already?

Answer (score 0):

you should try pip3 to install python3's module

```
pip3 install BeautifulSop4
```

Comment: My problem is with running python 2.7 where the packages are not being recognized.  >python -m pip install BeautifulSoup,mechanize Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): BeautifulSoup in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoup-3.2.1-py2.7.egg
You are using pip version 8.0.2, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command. Pip upgrade also did not cut it.

Comment: File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 524, in select_form
mechanize._mechanize.FormNotFoundError: no form matching name 'signinWidget'

Comment: no form matching name 'signinWidget' ,  is  No name is found in the form of the table ， Is not the problem that  the packages are not being recognized

Comment: You should confirm the name of form. This has a similar problem，[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020117/mechanize-mechanize-formnotfounderror-no-form-matching-name-q/16020863)

Comment: I really appreciate you pointing me in the right direction. The script is trying to access login on 'seller central.amazon.in'. I verified the widget using 'inspect element' and the form name is 'signinWidget'. This used to work before but stopped after few months. Once again, my apologies, if I am missing anything obvious.

Comment: I try to find the form name is 'signinWidget' on 'seller central.amazon.in', but there no form name is 'signinWidget' , you can try ' $("form[name='signinWidget']") ' command in console , there has a form name is 'signIn' , you can use $("form") or $('form[name="signIn"]')  command to find it in console